# Highchart inner donut name as header for outer donut tooltip

Tags: highcharts, donut-chart

I am trying to set the inner donut name as the header for outer donuts tooltip in highchart. Can anyone please help me on this. In the example link chrome displayed on the inner pie chart should appear as header for all the chrome breakdowns in the outer donut's tool tip.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut

Thanks,
Sarath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your own [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) callback.

It would be helpful if you link the outer points with the inner points when you are creating data for the chart.

```
versionsData.push({
  name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
  browserName: categories[i], //additional property for linking with the inner series
  y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
  color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
});
```

Now, in the formatter you can check for the name series - and depending on it - return the default formatter or a modified text which in the header will include `point.browserName`

```
tooltip: {
  valueSuffix: '%',
  formatter: function(tooltip) {
    if (this.series.name === 'Versions') {
      return ('<span style="font-size: 10px">' + this.point.browserName + '</span><br/>').concat(tooltip.bodyFormatter([this]));
    }

    return tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/wss6896b/

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly I was looking for.